# Is it bad practice to use @ControllerAdvice on static nested classes?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I need two separate ControllerAdvice-annotated classes in my application: one of them handles specific exceptions, the other one is a default-handler with lower @Order for all unexpected exceptions. However, they share some custom logic for building a ResponseEntity from the handled exceptions.

In order to keep the code in one place and make the shared logic available to them, I thought to put both classes as static nested classes into one outer class, like so:

```
public class ExceptionHandler {

  private static ResponseEntity handleError(Exception ex, String message){ 
    // shared exception handling 
  }
  
  @ControllerAdvice
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  static class SpecializedExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity handleMyException(MyException ex){
      return handleError(ex, "Custom Exception");
    }
  }

  @ControllerAdvice
  static class DefaultExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity handleAllOtherExceptions(Exception ex){
      return handleError(ex, "Other Exception");
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine and I couldn't come up with arguments against it on my own, so maybe you can help me out.

Comment: one argument to separate the classes is that for example in future you may want to have many custom exceptions like MyException and for each one you will add one static class in ExceptionHandler? it will make your code unreadable and difficult to maintain.

Comment: The idea was to have all specifically handled exceptions, or rather their handlers, in the SpecializedExceptionHandler together. I really just need the DefaultExceptionHandler separated with a lower priority because of CompletionExceptions getting wrapped around exceptions from a certain part of the code.

Comment: ‘Static inner’ is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general wisdom is for code units (classes in Java) to have a single purpose. Although the implementations are technically single purpose, they're unnecessarily entangled by coexisting in the same file.

It would be better to split them up, something like this:

```
public interface BaseExceptionHandler {

    default ResponseEntity handleError(Exception ex, String message) { 
        // shared exception handling 
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SpecializedExceptionHandler implements BaseExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity handleMyException(MyException ex){
        return handleError(ex, "Custom Exception");
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class DefaultExceptionHandler implements BaseExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity handleAllOtherExceptions(Exception ex){
        return handleError(ex, "Other Exception");
    }
}
```

This also removes the use of `static`, making them more conventional.

If you prefer inheritance style:

```
public abstract class BaseExceptionHandler {

    ResponseEntity handleError(Exception ex, String message) { 
        // shared exception handling 
    }
}

public class SpecializedExceptionHandler extends BaseExceptionHandler {
   ...
```

If you prefer `static` method style:

```
public final class ExceptionHandlerUtils {

    public static ResponseEntity handleError(Exception ex, String message) { 
        // shared exception handling 
    }
}

public class SpecializedExceptionHandler extends BaseExceptionHandler {
    // impl uses ExceptionHandlerUtils.handleError()
```

Comment: Why did you put the excpetion handling method in interface, is there need for that, why not just call that static method and not overload code with "implements BaseExceptionHandler" for each Exception handler class?

Comment: @Black I chose a style that I felt most closely reflected OP's intention. I've added other styles to my answer. They are all "OK" IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the update!